If $p$ is a prime dividing $|G|$, is $H_p$ a proper subgroup of $G$?
Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $H_m:=\{g^m, g\in G\}$, for $m\in\{1,\dots,|G|\}$. Some facts are:

$H_m\le G$, for every $m$$^\dagger$
$H_1=G$
$H_{|G|}=\{e\}$

Question:
If $p$ is a prime dividing $|G|$, is $H_p$ a proper subgroup of $G$?
I've tried by contradiction: assume $H_p=G$; then, for every $h\in G$, there is some $g\in G$ (depending on $h$) such that $h=g^p$. This is where I'm stuck.
Context:
I'm wishing to use the (hopefully affirmative) answer to this question to prove Cauchy's theorem for abelian groups. More explicitly:
Let ${\rm diag}(G^p):=$ $\{(g,\dots,g)\in G^p, g\in G\}$, where $G_p$ is the direct product of $p$ copies of $G$. By the abelianess of $G$, ${\rm diag}(G^p)\curvearrowright G$ via $(g,\dots,g)\cdot x:=g^px$. The stabilizer of $x=1$ has order $|\{g\in G\mid g^p=1\}|$. Moreover, ${\rm diag}(G^p)$ has order $|G|$ and the orbit of $x=1$ has size $<|G|$. Then, applying the orbit-stabilizer theorem to $x=1$, it follows that $|\{g\in G\mid g^p=1\}|>1$, namely $G$ has an element of order $p$.
The affirmative answer to the question would justify the bold-typed claim, thus completing this proof of Cauchy's theorem for abelian groups.
From the comments:
What I (convolutedly) proved by group actions has a very straightforward proof: $H_p$ is the image under the endomorphism $x\mapsto x^p$ ($G$ is abelian!), whose kernel is $K:=\{x\in G\mid x^p=1\}$. By the first homomorphism theorem, $G/K\cong H_p$, and hence $H_p<G$ (properly) if and only if $G$ has an element of order $p$. Most probably, an independent elementary proof of $H_p<G$ doesn't exists, as otherwise this first-homomorphism-theorem-based proof of Cauchy's theorem (for abelian groups) would be widely used as the standard one. Which is not, to the best of my knowledge.

$^\dagger$Let $h,k\in H_m$; then $h=x^m$ and $k=y^m$, for some $x,y\in G$, and hence $hk=x^my^m=(xy)^m$ (bacause $G$ is abelian). So, $hk\in H_m$.

The answer is yes, and $G$ need not to be abelian. Take $g$ be an element of maximal $p$ power order in $G$. Then $h^p=g$ would imply that the order of $g$ is not maximal among $p$ power order elements. So $g$ is not in $H_p$.

How do you know that such a $g$ exists, @EnguerrandMoulinier? In my context, Cauchy's theorem is not yet at hand (let alone Sylow). If this has an easy answer, you may want to include it in a full answer, so that I can link to it afterwards.

The neutral element is a prime power order of $G$. As $G$ is finite, some maximal $p$ power order element of $G$ must exist.

@EnguerrandMoulinier Your reasoning is correct just if $p$ divides the order of $h$.

@Deif Well, if $g$ is of order a power of $p$ and $h^p = g$, then $h$ is of order a power of $p$, thus $p$ divides the order of $h$

Enguerrand's claim that this is true even in the nonabelian case is potentially confusing. It's true that $H_p$ is a proper subset, but it is not in general a subgroup, so it's not true to say it's a proper subgroup. Just adding this as a minor clarification.

The function $G\to G$ given by $x\mapsto x^n$ is a group homomorphism for any $n$, so proving $G_n\neq G$ is equivalent to proving the existence of a non-identity element of order dividing $n$. To prove $G_p\neq G$ you are essentially going to have to in-line a proof of Cauchy's theorem.

@EnguerrandMoulinier but how do you prove the element of maximal order is not $e$? Your argument only works if $g\neq e\neq h$.

@ArturoMagidin Okay you are right, I did something wrong as I really use Cauchy without saying it, and the author wants a proof without Cauchy. That's on me, sorry

@EnguerrandMoulinier It's not "wrong", it just doesn't avoid Cauchy.

@EnguerrandMoulinier: if $G$ is not abelian, then $H_m$ need not be a subgroup: consider $G=S_3$ and $m=2$. If instead you consider the subgroup generated by $H_m$, then you could end up with all of $G$, as the example just given illustrates.

@Kan't: the proof that this statement is equivalent to Cauchy's theorem (for abelian groups) is much simpler than what you sketch: $H_p$ is the image of the group endomorphism $x\mapsto x^p$. Now just apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Yes, that's way more straightforward than mine, @AlexB. The point as to whether we can prove $H_p<G$ without Cauchy's theorem (for $G$ abelian) remains. But, most probably, an independent elementary proof of $H_p<G$ doesn't exists, as otherwise this first-homomorphism-theorem-based proof of Cauchy's theorem (for abelian groups) would be widely used as the standard option. Which is clearly not. Thanks.
